# how to .show() a hidden div in a jquery dialog, that .load()'s an external php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

at the top I have

```
echo '
      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     ';
```

then later...

```
echo "<a href='#' name='new' style='text-decoration:none;font-size:0.9em;color:#999999'><i>add new field?</i><a/><br /><br />";
echo "<div style='display:none'><input type='text' name='cat[]' value='' /></div>";

$(function() {  //this does absolutely nothing btw
    $("#new").click(function() {
         $(this).next("div").show("slow");
    });
});
```

but this script is loaded via jquery from another page when a button is clicked like this...

```
        $("#name").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'name',
            open: function() { $("#name").load("script.php"); }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your selector from `$('#new')` to `$('[name=new]')`, or add an `id='new'` attribute to the anchor.

Comment: A assumed you are showing snippets of code so ignored the mixing of PHP and Javascript, however that should have raised an error. Can you try just loading the file containing the first two pieces of code and seeing if that works.